# Windows 8: Launch application on logoff

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-8

I created an application (.NET Windows Forms) which shall be launched after a user presses the "Logoff" key in Windows 8. I created a gpo in my domain environment which works in Windows 7. However, Windows 8 shows instantly the logoff screen and there is no chance for my application to pop up. Is there some kind of GPO that prevents the application from showing up?

The purpose of the application is to show users their projects and they have to tell the application how long they worked for a specific project. This would be nice if this works on logoff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from [Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007](https://superuser.com/users/23133/%C6%AC%E1%B4%87c%CA%9C%CE%B9%E1%B4%87007) from [my superuser-thread](https://superuser.com/questions/993460/windows-8-launch-application-on-logoff?):

> The Windows 8 logoff screen is the topmost window, and that's why you can't see Windows launched during Logoff.
>
> A fix that has been [suggested to work](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/79c57e66-69f6-4d96-b056-52ff61411e74/windows-8-logoff-script-problem?forum=w8itprogeneral) is to enable the `Display instructions in logoff scripts as they run` group policy in `User Configuration/Administrative Templates/System/Scripts`
>
> **Description**
>
> Displays the instructions in logoff scripts as they run.
>
> Logoff scripts are batch files of instructions that run when the user logs off. By default, the system does not display the instructions in the logoff script.`
>
> If you enable this policy, the system displays each instruction in the logoff script as it runs. The instructions appear in a command window. This setting is designed for advanced users.
>
> If you disable this policy or do not configure it, the instructions are suppressed.